# Get data from phpmyadmin using another machine

Tags: android, eclipse, phpmyadmin

I am building an android app with the following code:

```
try{
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/tut.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception 1 caugt");
        }
```

This apps works fine in my computer.
I want everyone download this app can use it and read the data from phpmyadmin.
can any one teach my how to do this?
(I want the data in phpmyadmin can be read from public user.)
And do I need to change the code?

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://XXXXXXXXX/tut.php");
```

Comment: Its not the code you have to change, but instead of hosting the database locally on your machine you have to host it online.

Comment: How to host it online? I am new to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your app available to everyone you have to host your data online. There are many ways you can achieve this and it depends a lot on what type of application you intend to distribute.

If you just want to start trying out how things work you can buy a normal web hosting which supports mysql and php. This will cost you between 30 to 60 euros for a year. You setup your database, upload your php api and your good to go.

If you want a more professional approach you can choose to host in the cloud via cloud services the like of Amazon Web Services and Microsoft's Azure. This has a big learning curve but it gives you total control over the server and also huge experience.

Comment: actually, i had another database(mysql,php) from my school.     I think this one already put online, because i can access the data on any machine.     Lets say the websit is "www2.xxx.xxxx.xxx/xxxxxxxx/tut.php", and i put this "HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www2.xxx.xxxx.xxx/xxxxxxxx/tut.php");", it cannot  connect.

Comment: If the code works on local URL , you dont have to change any code to work with an online URL. If you can't connect its not because of the code but because the availability of the host

Comment: i find out the problem, it's different data name. after i change it, it can run on different machine. Thank you for your kind explaination, i'm now know more.

Comment: its was nice meeting you !! happy coding